# Unzip multipart files created from Mac in Windows

Tags: windows, zip, archiving, extract

This is how I created a multipart archive from Mac;

```
zip -r -s 1g archive.zip long\ folder\ name/
```

This creates files like archive.zip, archive.z01 and so on. Now I am trying to unzip this archive in Windows.

I have tried;

```
copy /B archive.z* unified.zip
```

but unified.zip cannot be unzipped. Also tried 7Zip but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried `7zip` on the original `archive.zip` (with the other parts in the same directory)? I've not seen a multi-part `zip` file, but it certainly works fine on a multi-part `rar`.

Comment: Yes. Tried 7Zip on the original and also with all parts selected. 7Zip tells me 'Is not archive'.

Comment: First. Try zip single small file on Mac. Try unzip it on windows. Can you provide a samples?

Comment: See 7Zip instructions at http://mintywhite.com/vista/extract-multipart-archives-000-001-r01-r02-7zip/ and at http://wiki.tesnexus.com/index.php/Combining_multipart_files_using_7-zip; hope that works for you.